# Can I write a C++ functor that accepts both a raw pointer and a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, adapter, smart-pointers, functor

Given the following:

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar() const;
};

struct IsEqual : public std::unary_function<Foo*, bool>
{
    int val;
    IsEqual(int v) : val(v) {}

    bool operator()(const Foo* elem) const
    {
        return elem->bar() == val;
    }
};
```

I have a container of `Foo*` and I use `std::find_if` and `std::not1` to find out if there are any elements in the container where `bar()` returns something different from a given value.  The code looks like this:

```
// Are all elements equal to '2'?
bool isAllEqual(const std::vector<Foo*> &vec)
{
    return find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::not1(IsEqual(2))) == vec.end();
}
```

Fast-forward into the future and I now have a different container, this time containing `std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>`.  I'd love to simply re-use my functor in an overloaded version of `isAllEqual()`.  But I can't.  `Foo*` and `shared_ptr<Foo>` are different types.  And I need to inherit from `unary_function` so I can use `not1`.  It'd be more elegant if I could avoid writing the same functor twice.

**Questions:**

- Is there any way to write `IsEqual` so it can use both raw and smart pointers?
- Did I handcuff myself by using `std::not1`?  Should I just write `IsNotEqual` instead?

Restrictions:

1. I can't use anything from the boost library.
2. Our compiler isn't cool enough to support C++0x lambdas.

Comment: This sounds like an example where templates would be nice.

Comment: @Kristo: Is your compiler cool enough to provide other C++0x stuff, like `std::begin`?

Comment: @Ben, we're using gcc 4.1.2, so probably not.  `std::begin` and `std::end` should be trivial to write though.

Comment: @Kristo: Well, the only purpose of using `begin(coll)` instead of `coll.begin()` is to support raw arrays as a possible container type, so feel free to go either way according to your expected use cases.

Comment: @Kristo: do you have the `all_of` algorithm in your implementation of the STL ? Seems more adapted than `find_if` to the case at hand.

Comment: @Matthieu, no we don't have it.  I'd never even heard of it until now.  I'm guess I'm basically rolling my own version of it.

Comment: @Kristo: too bad, it's normally a shiny new algorithm in C++0x along with `any_of` and `none_of` (and the infamous `copy_if`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// --*-- C++ --*--

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// Template unary function example.
template <typename T>
struct IsEqual : public std::unary_function<T, bool>
{
    int v;

    IsEqual (int v) : v (v) {}

    bool operator () (const T & elem) const
    {
        return elem ? elem->bar () == v : false;
    }
};

// Generic algorithm implementation example...
template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool isAllEqual (const T1 & c, T2 v)
{
    return find_if (
        c.begin (), c.end (),
        std::not1 (IsEqual <typename T1::value_type> (v))) == c.end ();
}

// Some arbitrary pointer wrapper implementation,
// provided just for an example, not to include any
// specific smart pointer implementation.
template <typename T>
class WrappedPtr
{
    const T *v;

public:
    typedef void (WrappedPtr<T>::*unspecified_boolean_type) () const;

    WrappedPtr (const T *v) : v (v) {}

    const T *operator -> () const { return v; }

    operator unspecified_boolean_type () const
    {
        return v != NULL ?
            &WrappedPtr<T>::unspecified_boolean_true : NULL;
    }

private:
    void unspecified_boolean_true () const {}
};

// Example of structure that could be used with our algorithm.
struct Foo
{
    int v;

    Foo (int v) : v (v) {}

    int bar () const
    {
        return v;
    }
};

// Usage examples...
int main ()
{
    Foo f1 (2), f2 (2);

    // Example of using raw pointers...
    {
        std::vector<Foo *> vec;
        vec.push_back (NULL);
        vec.push_back (&f1);
        vec.push_back (&f2);

        if (isAllEqual (vec, 2))
            std::cout << "All equal to 2" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Not all equal to 2" << std::endl;
    }

    // Example of using smart pointers...
    {
        std::vector< WrappedPtr<Foo> > vec;
        vec.push_back (NULL);
        vec.push_back (&f1);
        vec.push_back (&f2);

        if (isAllEqual (vec, 2))
            std::cout << "All equal to 2" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Not all equal to 2" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for checking for a null pointer in `operator()`.  Looks good to me.

Comment: @Vlad: Doesn't work with good old ordinary arrays.  Also, is it a good idea for `unary_function<Arg, Result>::Arg` to be different from the parameter type of `operator()()`?

Comment: @Ben: I think for constant reference to the same type it is OK. To support arrays, I guess for simple arrays you have to have a different specialization like template <size_t Len> void foo(const (&array) [Len])... or something like that.

Comment: @Vlad: `std::begin` and `std::end` are already specialized for arrays.

Comment: @Vlad: But apparently they're new in C++0x :(

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsEqual : public std::unary_function<const T&, bool>
{
    int val;
    IsEqual(int v) : val(v) {}

    bool operator()(const T& elem) const
    {
        return elem->bar() == val;
    }
};

template<typename T>
IsEqual<T> DeduceEqualityComparer(int v, T) { return IsEqual<T>(v); }

// Are all elements equal to '2'?
template<typename TContainer>
bool isAllEqual(const TContainer& coll)
{
    using std::begin; // in C++0x, or else write this really simple function yourself
    using std::end;
    if (begin(coll) == end(coll)) return true;
    return find_if(begin(coll), end(coll), std::not1(DeduceEqualityComparer(2, *begin(coll)))) == end(coll);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I like it.  However, it's not really any less typing than `IsEqual<std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo> >` (and then I wouldn't have to write the deducer).  +1 anyway though.

Comment: @Kristo: Ok, but now make `isAllEqual` a template as well, code coming.

Comment: You could also give `IsEqual` a default template argument: `template<typename T = Foo*> struct IsEqual...`  And then continue to use `IsEqual` as before for iterators to `Foo*`.

Comment: @Kristo: Now `isAllEqual` (shouldn't that be `areAllEqual`?) works with vectors/lists/sets/deques of both raw and smart pointers.  This is where the deducer helper function really shines.

Comment: This example has unnecessary copying of the objects of type `T` in IsEqual` structure. This could be a problem in those cases where copying shared pointer is a relatively expensive operation. You can avoid that by using a reference (which will work as a reference to smart pointer of reference to raw pointer).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is wrong since you want T to be `TContainer::value_type` not `TContainer::iterator`. Also, why not drop the deducer and just do `IsEqual<TContainer::value_type>` directly?

Comment: @Chris: Good catch.  Not all containers define `value::type`.  Edits coming.

Comment: @Chris, I was about to ask the same question.  I get what the code is trying to do (syntax nitpicks aside).  The bigger problem IMO is: what if the container is empty?  It's not valid to dereference `begin()` in that case.  [Vlad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433155/can-i-write-a-c-functor-that-accepts-both-a-raw-pointer-and-a-smart-pointer/4433359#4433359) doesn't have that problem.

Comment: @Kristo: I thought of that, and `begin()` doesn't get dereferenced if the container is empty.

Comment: @Ben, why doesn't your newest code check for `coll.empty()`?  Is it to minimize the requirements on what the container supports?

Comment: @Kristo: It tests `begin == end`, which is a little more verbose way of doing the same check.

Comment: @Ben, oh I get it.  Raw arrays don't support `empty()`.

Answer (score 2):

My shot would be something like this:

```
template<typename PtrToFoo>
struct IsEqual : public std::unary_function<PtrToFoo, bool>
{
    int val;
    IsEqual(int v) : val(v) {}

    bool operator()(PtrToFoo elem) const
    {
        return elem->bar() == val;
    }
};
```

You'll have a different `operator()` instantiation for everything dereferencable with `->`, so raw pointers and smart pointers.

Comment: You can do that?  I thought the first template argument to `unary_function` had to match the argument type of `operator()`.

Comment: No, you can't.  Yes, it does.

Comment: Right obviously, I had overlooked that :) Thanks for pointing that out (fixed)

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe do something tricky with implicit conversions:

```
class IsEqualArg {
public:
  // Implicit conversion constructors!
  IsEqualArg(Foo* foo) : ptr(foo) {}
  IsEqualArg(const std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>& foo) : ptr(&*foo) {}
private:
  Foo* ptr;
  friend struct IsEqual;
};

struct IsEqualArg : public std::unary_function<IsEqualArg, bool> {
  bool operator()( const IsEqualArg& arg ) const;
  //...
};
```

But I'd really rather just write a `IsNotEqual`.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer is really the only thing you can do in c++03.  In C++0x though, and/or with boost::bind, you don't need to inherit from unary_function.  This allows you to use a templated () operator.  You can usually get away with the same in C++03 but I think that it's technically incorrect to do so.

Comment: TR1 `bind` might be ok.  I'd have to check with the people who work with our code.  And it's not incorrect to write a templated `operator()`.  It's the use of `not1` that's the sticking point.